# Using two network adapters on the same Windows 10 machine

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking

On my system, I have two network adapters. One is a PDAnet private network that I use to tether internet over my LTE connection (because it's faster than my home internet). The other is a conventional wifi adapter that I mainly use to SSH to my Raspberry Pi, but it has access to internet as well if I disconnect the PDAnet.

My question is, how does Windows know which adapter to use for internet access? Does it test the speed or is there some priority setting inside the network settings? Is there some way to use BOTH adapters at the same time for even faster internet access?

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: This is handled by [interface metric value](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-priority-order-network-adapters-windows-10) of the adapter.  You likely will run into problems by attempting to use two adapter in two different subnets. Having two adapters will not increase the speed of your connection.

Comment: in order: it uses the default route, and if there is more than one, it uses the default route with the lowest metric. You cannot use both the adapters together in this case. the reason is a little complicated. you can either use two nics that have been "Bonded" by the OS, but then they need to be on the same network, or you can put one nic on two networks, but then only use then the nic is only used for traffic to that network. there must be only one default path that Internet traffic takes under normal circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple elements in how an OS decides what to do. The simplest overview is that if there are multiple devices a packet can be sent via the OS is programmed with an order  of preference based on the (theoretical  not actual tested for this pc) expected performance of the Interface.  This typically prefers ethernet over wifi, and the first device in its class the OS knows (eg the first ethernet adaptor if you have multiple identical ones).

The OS implements these decisions by modifying the routing table. An ordered list of routes is set up, with all appropriate entries for all devices, along with priorities.  When a packet is sent it is sent using the first route that matches.

At the top of the lists are direct routes to connected systems. (These are calculated based on ip address and netmask)

Next come specific routes to other devices through a gateway/router - these also are broken up using netmasks. They are not typically present on an end user PC unless a vpn to is being used. Netmasks themselves have an order - with more specific netmasks (ie one grouping fewer ips) is preferred.

After this comes the "default gateway" which is where unknown packets go. (in reality this is just a special case of the previous rule with a netmask catching everything).

Devices like VPNs and hardware that balances traffic is typically done by creating a virtual device that follows the above rules.

If you have 2 interfaces and want to control which interface may be appropriate way is to associate different networks to the devices - eg 192.168.x.x to your normal connections and 10.0.0.x to the devices which connect to your Pi. (although there are more complex solutions which can work better - but which need a good understanding if netmasks and your specific requirements)

Answer (score 0):

Windows is pretty good at [automatically picking](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/automatic-metric-for-ipv4-routes) the best performing adapter available and using it. It is also possible to 'load balance' between multiple adapters on a single machine. [Here is a simple tutorial for windows about using more than one adapter at the same time.](https://windowsreport.com/combine-internet-connections/) Other software *channel bonding* solutions are only a google search away! Fair warning, this isn't a silver bullet and you might not see a performance boost. Your mileage may vary :)

Comment: A load balancer by itself will not get you faster download speeds.  Likewise, a load balancer seems out of place, for the author's problem set.  They have a Raspberry Pi on their internal network, that is otherwise inaccessible on the adapter that is tethered to their phone, a load balancer wouldn't resolve that problem set.   The solution to having two ISPs is typically an expensive one to solve, since it requires a switch, and setting up a single VLAN that can access both subnets.

Comment: I may have misunderstood OPs issue, and @Ramhound is correct. Generally 'load balancing' is never a solution to client device slow download speeds. I misspoke, channel bonding not load balancing was what I meant to say.  Software such as Speedify provides demonstrably improved throughput. Also as Rahmound pointed out, the Raspberry Pi will not benefit from the desktops connection to multiple ISPs.