# 2 Network Adapters of PC connected to same router, how does the connection work?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, ethernet

2 NICs connected to same router.

Speedtest 1:
When connected via ethernet only, I get 100Mbps up/download speed.
When connected via WiFi 5GHz only, I get 300Mbps upload (capped by my internet service), 150Mbps download speed.

Speedtest 2:
I look into my router's interface statistics table (Mikrotik HAP AX2).

When 2 of them are connected at the same time to same router, I get varying connections active at one point. Sometimes the WiFi is active on both upload and download test, sometimes WiFi is active during download, then ethernet connection is active during upload, and sometimes only the ethernet is active during both download and upload tests.

So who decides which one dominates. How does it actually work?

Comment: What research have you done regarding this? There are a few questions on this site regarding this setup. What does WiFi have to do with your setup: your title and first parts of the Q are about a computer with 2 NICs and I do not see what WiFi has to do with the situation. I think this question from a few years ago addresses your "what is happening" question: https://superuser.com/questions/1659806/using-two-network-adapters-on-the-same-windows-10-machine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using two network adapters on the same Windows 10 machine](https://superuser.com/questions/1659806/using-two-network-adapters-on-the-same-windows-10-machine)

Comment: So your system will only have one active route (with exit interface) to a given destination at a time. In this case, I believe your OS is trying to prefer wifi because the connection is faster, but is less reliable, and more subject to changes in OS power state, so its likely falling back to the wired nic at times, and using the wifi at others. that said though, unless you are in the middle of a state change, only one nic is carrying traffic at a time.